# Is there a way to display two Columns of a Table as two lines in a ListView?

Tags: sql, listview, javafx, tableview

I am developing a little Zettelkasten-app. The content of the Zettel are stored in an SQL table. I want a ListView in a Sidebar to show the existing Zettel and display the Header as well as a Snippet of Text, like a thumbnail for Text, to choose which Zettel is loaded into the editor.

This is what i envision:

[image: mock-up]

Is there a way to do this using ListView?

If not, how would u approach it? Is there a way to display the columns of a TableView in horizontal order?

Herzl Ich

Comment: You mention a TableView, but do you want a TableView at all, or just a ListView with customized cells?  It would help if your question included a mock-up of the UI you are trying to build as an image.

Comment: @jewelsea i just added a drawing, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to load the data into both Nodes. Use the `ListView's` `setCellFactory` to display the columns you want to display. Finally, bind the `ListView's` `selectionModelProperty` to the `TableView's` `selectionModelProperty`.

---

### Key code

```
listView.setCellFactory((ListView<UserAccount> param) -> 
{
    
    Label lblFirstName = new Label();
    Label lblLastName = new Label();
    Label lblAbout = new Label();
    VBox vbRoot = new VBox(new HBox(lblFirstName, lblLastName), lblAbout);
    
    final ListCell<UserAccount> cell = new ListCell<UserAccount>() {
        @Override 
        public void updateItem(UserAccount item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (item != null) {
                lblFirstName.setText(item.getFirstName());
                lblLastName.setText(item.getLastName());
                lblAbout.setText(item.getAbout());
                setGraphic(vbRoot);
            }
        }
    };
    
    return cell;        
});

listView.selectionModelProperty().bind(table.selectionModelProperty());
```

---

### Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        TableView<UserAccount> table = new TableView();

        // Create column UserName (Data type of String).
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> userNameCol = new TableColumn("Username");
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");     
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        TableColumn<UserAccount, String> activeCol = new TableColumn("Active");
        table.getColumns().addAll(userNameCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol, activeCol);

        // Get value from property of UserAccount. .
        userNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getUsername()));
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getEmail()));
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getFirstName()));
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getLastName()));
        activeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getAbout()));
      
        // Display row data
        ObservableList<UserAccount> list = getUserList();
        table.setItems(list);
      
        ListView<UserAccount> listView = new ListView(list);
        listView.setCellFactory((ListView<UserAccount> param) -> 
        {
            
            Label lblFirstName = new Label();
            Label lblLastName = new Label();
            Label lblAbout = new Label();
            VBox vbRoot = new VBox(new HBox(lblFirstName, lblLastName), lblAbout);
            
            final ListCell<UserAccount> cell = new ListCell<UserAccount>() {
                @Override 
                public void updateItem(UserAccount item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        lblFirstName.setText(item.getFirstName());
                        lblLastName.setText(item.getLastName());
                        lblAbout.setText(item.getAbout());
                        setGraphic(vbRoot);
                    }
                }
            };
            
            return cell;        
        });
        
        listView.selectionModelProperty().bind(table.selectionModelProperty());
        
        HBox root = new HBox(listView, table);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        stage.setTitle("TableView and ListView");

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 450, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    private ObservableList<UserAccount> getUserList() {

        UserAccount user1 = new UserAccount(1L, "smith", "smith@gmail.com", "Susan", "Smith", "I am your best friend!");
        UserAccount user2 = new UserAccount(2L, "mcneil", "mcneil@gmail.com", "Anne", "McNeil", "I am not your best friend!");
        UserAccount user3 = new UserAccount(3L, "white", "white@gmail.com", "Kenvin", "White", "I would like to have fun one day");
        ObservableList<UserAccount> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(user1, user2, user3);
        
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

### UserAccount

```
public class UserAccount {
   private Long id;
   private String username;
   private String email;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String about;

   public UserAccount(Long id, String username, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String about) {
       this.id = id;
       this.username = username;
       this.email = email;
       this.firstName = firstName;
       this.lastName = lastName;
       this.about = about;
   }

   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getUsername() {
       return username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
       return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getAbout() {
       return about;
   }

   public void setAbout(String about) {
       this.about = about ;
   }
}
```

---

### Output

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer based on your question update. All of the ideas are still the same.

Comment: tysm:) this helps!